# onDblClick event on a non-editable text box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need to perform an action on double click of a text box, but the `onDblClick` event does not seem to register when the text box is **not editable** (i.e. greyed out). Is there something I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ,

The legacy code was using the 'disabled' property of the element to toggle editability of 
the text box. So that also disables events on the text box.

> textElement.disabled = true;

To fix this,

I used the 'readOnly' property of the element for the editability toggling needs and now it registers events.

```
textElement.readOnly = true;
```

Thanks for reading!

Rohan.

Answer (score 3):

How about applying the onDblClick event to the parent div your text box is in?

e.g.

```
<div ondblclick="someAction()"><input type="text" readonly="true" /></div>
```